# Not getting values in datatable while Updating gridview row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have 5 rows in `gridview` in which I am trying to update one row, While updating, I wrote below code:-

```
protected void GrdProspective1_UpdateCommand(object sender, Obout.Grid.GridRecordEventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["grdEdit"] != null)
    {
        DtCombo = (DataTable)Session["grdEdit"];
    }
    else
    {
        BindDatatable();
    }

    DataRow[] dataProsUpdate = DtCombo.Select("SR_NO = " + e.Record["SR_NO"]);

    dataProsUpdate[0]["PARTY_NAME"] = e.Record["PARTY_NAME"];
    dataProsUpdate[0]["FLAT_NO"] = e.Record["FLAT_NO"];
    dataProsUpdate[0]["LEASE_NUM"] = e.Record["LEASE_NUM"];
    dataProsUpdate[0]["ACTION"] = e.Record["ACTION"];
    dataProsUpdate[0]["NO_OF_DAYS"] = e.Record["NO_OF_DAYS"];
    dataProsUpdate[0]["REMARKS"] = e.Record["REMARKS"];

    GrdProspective1.DataSource = DtCombo;
    GrdProspective1.DataBind();
    AddToViewState("GrdProspective1");
}
```

But in this, I am getting error as

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

I am confused why datatable is emppty when there are 5 rows in the gridview

My datatable code:-

```
public void BindDatatable()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataRow dr;

    DataColumn SR_NO;
    DataColumn PARTY_NAME;
    DataColumn FLAT_NO;
    DataColumn LEASE_NUM;
    DataColumn ACTION;
    DataColumn NO_OF_DAYS;
    DataColumn REMARKS;

    DtCombo = new DataTable();

    SR_NO = new DataColumn("SR_NO", typeof(Int32));
    PARTY_NAME = new DataColumn("PARTY_NAME", typeof(String));
    FLAT_NO = new DataColumn("FLAT_NO", typeof(Int32));
    LEASE_NUM = new DataColumn("LEASE_NUM", typeof(Int32));
    ACTION = new DataColumn("ACTION", typeof(String));
    NO_OF_DAYS = new DataColumn("NO_OF_DAYS", typeof(Int32));
    REMARKS = new DataColumn("REMARKS", typeof(String));

    DtCombo.Columns.Add(SR_NO);
    DtCombo.Columns.Add(PARTY_NAME);
    DtCombo.Columns.Add(FLAT_NO);
    DtCombo.Columns.Add(LEASE_NUM);
    DtCombo.Columns.Add(ACTION);
    DtCombo.Columns.Add(NO_OF_DAYS);
    DtCombo.Columns.Add(REMARKS);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete solution:

```
protected void GrdProspective1_UpdateCommand(object sender, Obout.Grid.GridRecordEventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["grdEdit"] != null)
    {
        DtCombo = (DataTable)Session["grdEdit"];
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }

    DataRow[] dataProsUpdate = DtCombo.Select("SR_NO = " + e.Record["SR_NO"]);

    dataProsUpdate[0]["PARTY_NAME"] = e.Record["PARTY_NAME"];
    dataProsUpdate[0]["FLAT_NO"] = e.Record["FLAT_NO"];
    dataProsUpdate[0]["LEASE_NUM"] = e.Record["LEASE_NUM"];
    dataProsUpdate[0]["ACTION"] = e.Record["ACTION"];
    dataProsUpdate[0]["NO_OF_DAYS"] = e.Record["NO_OF_DAYS"];
    dataProsUpdate[0]["REMARKS"] = e.Record["REMARKS"];

    GrdProspective1.DataSource = DtCombo;
    GrdProspective1.DataBind();
    AddToViewState("GrdProspective1");
}

public void DisplayGridEdit() 
{ 
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT...", ObjPriCon); 

DtCombo = new DataTable(); 
OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd); 
da.Fill(DtCombo); 

GrdProspective1.DataSource = DtCombo; 
GrdProspective1.DataBind(); 
AddToViewState("GrdProspective1");
}
```

Comment: where to create exactly. as I am not binding grid on page_load but on some event

Comment: When you call BindDatatable(); then DtCombo will always have 0 rows. That's your problem.

Comment: Man, you only add columns You need to also add rows with data.

Comment: can u tell me how to add that ?? please

Comment: ok, so the rest will follow `row["SR_NO"] = 1; row["PARTY_NAME"] = 2;` ..... and so on RIGHT ?

Comment: also I tried dynamically like `row["SR_NO"] = SR_NO;` but getting error as `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataColumn' to type 'System.IConvertible'.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107310/discussion-between-coder-and-lesmian).